# Can "had" be used as a synonym for "make"?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

Here is the context:

> These pictures ***had*** me recall so many memories. Father, you have been missed and I missed all those days that I had spend with you. Probably I was the happiest kid that time, Still happy but not as happier as I was when my dad was live.

Can the word "had" be used synonymously (that is, interchangeably) with "made"?

Comment: "These pictures **made** me recall so many memories. Father, I **miss you and miss** all those days that I **spent** with you. I was probably happiest at that time. I'm still happy but not as **happy** as I was when my dad was **alive. Rest in peace, Father. I miss** the whole family. **I** can't wait for the wedding **so that I can** retake all these pictures again."

Comment: Good question in terms of the distinctions it forces you to make. To "have" someone do something does mean to *make* them do it, but the agent of "have" in this sense can't be an inanimate object. I would say that "have" in this sense most literally means "arrange for it to be done", which clearly demands a person as an agent. Hence, the pictures can *make* you feel something, but they can't *have* you feel something. Oddly enough, though, they can "have you __ing something": "Those pictures had me laughing." If I get my head around this before someone else does I'll make an answer out of it.

Comment: In a word, no. The construction _"These pictures had me recall so many memories"_ may be an attempt to use _to have_ in the sense of _to cause_ (_"**Have** him come to the interview a 5"_, e.g.) but its use in this context is not idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

Interchangeably?  No.

Yes, the structure "to *have* [someone] do [something]" can mean "to *make* [someone] do [something]":

> I **had** him run down to the store to get us some beer.

however, there are differences in nuance.  "Make" is much stronger and implies some kind of *coercion*, as if there are consequences for not doing what is asked.  Example:

> She **had** me clean up the garage.
>   She **made** me clean up the garage.

Both imply I didn't *want* to clean the garage, but "had" suggests I did it (somewhat) *voluntarily*, while "made" suggests it was *involuntary*.

As Luke Sawczak suggests in his comment, while an inanimate object can certainly *make* you feel something, we don't say that it can *have* you feel something.

> *(Yes)*: That movie was so sad, it **made** me cry.
>   *(No)*: That move was so sad, it **had** me cry.

However, using "have" is fine *if* you use the progressive:

> The movie was so sad it **had** me **crying**.
>
> The comedian **had** the audience **laughing** so hard they couldn't breathe.

Otherwise there are various other grammatical errors in your example.  One possible edit:

> These pictures had me **remembering so many things**. Father, you have been missed.  I **miss** all those days that I **spent** with you. **That was probably the happiest time in my life**.  **I am** still happy but not as **happy** as I was when my dad was **alive**.